# what is the reserved keyword for NaN in javascript?

Tags: javascript, nan

if i want to test the result of an expression and the function would return NaN
how would i check that?
examples: 
`$('amount').value.toInt()!='NaN'` 
^ does not work and i assume that the returned value is not a string,
`$('amount').value.toInt()!=NaN`
^ doesnt seem to work either and this one seems obvious

so how do i check wether the returned value is not a number?

Comment: It throws up undefined usually for any kind of craziness.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The NaN value is defined to be unequal to everything, including itself. Test if a value is NaN with the [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function, appropriately enough. (ECMAScript 6 adds a [`Number.isNan()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) function with different semantics for non-number arguments, but it's not supported in all browsers yet as of 2015).

There are two built-in properties available with a NaN value: the global [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) property (i.e. `window.NaN` in browsers), and [`Number.NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NaN). It is *not* a language keyword. In older browsers, the `NaN` property could be overwritten, with potentially confusing results, but with the [ECMAScript 5 standard it was made non-writable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.1).

- As @some pointed out in the comments, there is also the global function [isFinite()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) which may be useful.

Comment: @lock, it's 10 for a vote and 15 for an accept, so that's 25 (unless things have changed recently). And here's another 10, @Miles.

Comment: ohw sorry, wrong maths, thanks again to the very helpful programming community

Comment: There is also the isFinite function.

Comment: @Breton: NaN=1; alert(isNaN(NaN)); // alerts false. but isNaN("text") still returns true. It's the same with undefined. That too is just a global variable with the primitive value undefined. You can do undefined=1. Thats why one use: typeof variable === "undefined"

Comment: Note that JavaScript's `isNaN(...)` even returns `true` when passing it a non-number, like a primitive string, any object, or `undefined`. If one needs to test if something is a NaN *number*, one can use `a !== a` instead.

Comment: NaN = 1; NaN === 1; // false, even though NaN === NaN is true at this point

Comment: @jk7: You can't overwrite `NaN` (or `undefined`) in most browsers anymore, since this answer was originally written—see update

Comment: @Miles: I agree with your answer.  Just exploring how NaN works based the discussion in the comments.  Oddly enough, setting NaN=1 and then testing NaN === NaN now returns false when it had returned true yesterday - same version of Firefox, same test code.

Answer (score 2):

the best way to check the result of numeric operation against NaN is to aproach this way ,
example:

```
var x  = 0;
var y  = 0;
var result = x/y;  // we know that result will be NaN value
// to test if result holds a NaN value we should use the following code :

if(result !=result){
console.log('this is an NaN value');
}
```

and it's done.

the trick is that NaN can't be compared to any other value even with it self(NaN !=NaN is always true so we can take advantage of this and compare result against itself)

**this is JavaScript(a good and bizarre language)**

Answer (score 1):

Equality operator (== and ===) cannot be used to test a value against NaN. Use Number.isNaN() or isNaN() instead.

```js
NaN === NaN;        // false
Number.NaN === NaN; // false
isNaN(NaN);         // true
isNaN(Number.NaN);  // true
```