# Javascript variable / 'NaN' behaving weirdly

Tags: javascript, nan

I have a couple of textboxes, Which return javascript `Number` values if valid data is in the textboxes, otherwise `NaN`. I get this strange behavior. When I checked in `firebug` (both the textboxes are blank):

```
>>> hours
NaN
>>> minutes
NaN
>>> minutes == NaN
false
>>> hours == NaN
false
>>> hours == minutes
false
```

Why is it behaving so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NaN` is not equal to anything, not even `NaN`.

[Reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

[More detailed SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559792/what-is-the-reserved-keyword-for-nan-in-javascript)

For the authoritative source, see the [ECMAScript 5 Official Specification](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs/tc39-2009-043.pdf), sections [11.9.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.1) and [11.9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3):

```
1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then
     [...]
  c. If Type(x) is Number, then
     i. If x is NaN, return false.
    ii. If y is NaN, return false.
        [...]
```