# Comparing with NaN in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, floating-point

I have met this strange issue.

[image]

Why is so?! Should it be so?

Comment: Please add some text to the question, or ask your question at `imgur`... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript variable / 'NaN' behaving weirdly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083937/javascript-variable-nan-behaving-weirdly)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [MDN docs for `isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN):

> Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to
>   rely on the equality operators (== and ===) to determine whether a
>   value is NaN or not, because both NaN == NaN and NaN === NaN evaluate
>   to false. Hence, the necessity of an isNaN function.

use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) instead.

Comment: Intuitively: 3 is equal to 3, 4 is equal to 4, but non-number (say, "apple") is not necessarily equal to non-number (say, "orange").

Answer (score 5):

The reason behind this is that the rules of mathematics should be preserved. Otherwise, one would have `x == x + 1` if `x` is `NaN`, which is not a true relationship for any other value of x.

Answer (score 3):

that's why we use

```
isNaN(x)
```

it seems that x is a NaN object and it does not compare equal to another

Answer (score 2):

`NaN is` like an SQL `null`. It is never equal to anything, including itself. That's why there's the special case function `isNaN()` to safely test for `NaN`'s presence.