# Else is not executing ever

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to do a form, in which you put your first name, surname and city, if inputs are empty or have number in them it should say Please fill out all of available boxes and make sure there are no numbers. Else it should say quote using all of input informations. But the else is not working.

I tried cahnging the code and swapping some variables.

```js
function FillInfo()
{
         /* proměnné */
         var jmeno = document.forms ["SignUpForm"] ["jmeno"].value;
         var prijmeni = document.forms ["SignUpForm"] ["prijmeni"].value;
         var rok = document.forms ["SignUpForm"] ["mesto"].value;
         /*Kontrola zdali input políčka jsou prázdná či pokud bylo zadáno číslo */
         if(jmeno=="" || jmeno!=NaN || prijmeni=="" ||  prijmeni!= NaN || mesto=="" || mesto!=NaN){  

            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "Please fill out all of available boxes and make sure there are no numbers";    
      }
         else{     

            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML =  "Thank you" + " " + jmeno + " " + prijmeni + " from" + " " + mesto + "." + " " + "You are now being considered as our next adventurer. Good luck!";
    }
 }
```

```html
<div class="heading2">
        <div class="container2">
            <p>Do you want to travel troughout space? Then fill out our form!</p><br>
            <form name="SignUpForm">
                <input type="text" name="jmeno" placeholder="First name" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="prijmeni" placeholder="Last name" required><br>
                <input type="text" name="mesto" placeholder="City" required><br><br>
                <div id="info" class="well"></div>
                <input type="button" class="otherpage" onclick="FillInfo();" value="Submit" /><br><br>
                <a href="Mainpage.html" class="BeginLink">Return</a>
            </form>  
       </div>      
    </div>
```

Comment: logic is wrong and jmeno!=NaN is not right

Comment: Don't compare with `NaN` like that, it always makes the comparison `false`. But anyway, the `value` property of a DOM element *never* gives NaN. It is a string property. Use `isNaN()` function instead.

Comment: `NaN == NaN // false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if condition has to change, it always evaluates to `true`.

Instead of:

```
if (jmeno=="" || jmeno!=NaN || prijmeni=="" ||  prijmeni!= NaN || mesto=="" || mesto!=NaN) {
```

You should try:

```
if (jmeno==="" || isNaN(jmeno) || prijmeni==="" || isNaN(prijmeni) || mesto==="" || isNaN(mesto)) {
```

By the way, NaN is never equal to NaN, you have to use isNaN to know if it's a NaN.

However, this code is not what actually want. You want to check that there are **no numbers**, right? Depending on if you want *no digits at all* or *no number-only values*, you have to adapt your code. For example: `!isNaN(Number(jmeno))` to check if the value is a *number-only value*. The values you get from the text inputs are always strings so the conversion is needed.

Comment: EDIT2 solved it! thank you very much been wondering about that for a long time, couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @PavelFára You're welcome, I just edited so the EDIT2 is now the last paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong

```
jmeno=="" || jmeno!=NaN
```

Will always evaluate to true, I think you mean

```
jmeno=="" || isNaN(jmeno)
```

Obviously the rest of the statement needs editing too.

Comment: Not correct. Did you run that code to check? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10788166/5459839).

Comment: `isNaN(jmeno)`?

Comment: Edited to reflect