# JavaScript: what is NaN, Object or primitive?

Tags: javascript, nan

what is NaN, Object or primitive?

NaN - Not a Number

Comment: NaN is a property of the Number class

Comment: `typeof NaN == "number"`

Comment: NaN is like NULL.

you can refer this [SO Post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559792/what-is-the-reserved-keyword-for-nan-in-javascript

Comment: @rsplak: `NaN` is also a property of the global object, both have the value `NaN`.

Comment: Have a look at the specification [here](http://es5.github.com/#x8.5) and [here](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.1.1) for more information about `NaN`.

Comment: @avanigadhai Not exactly. `null` is actually a type, with only one value: `null`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NaN` is a primitive Number value. Just like `1`, `2`, etc.

Answer (score 15):

It's a primitive. You can check in a number of ways:

- `typeof NaN` gives "number," not "object."
- Add a property, it disappears. `NaN.foo = "hi"; console.log(NaN.foo) // undefined`
- `NaN instanceof Number` gives false (but we know it's a number, so it must be a primitive).

It wouldn't really make sense for NaN to be an object, because expressions like `0 / 0` need to result in `NaN`, and math operations always result in primitives. Having NaN as an object would also mean it could not act as a falsey value, which it does in some cases.

Comment: note that NaN !== NaN gives true.

Answer (score 2):

> NaN is a property of the global object.
>
> The initial value of NaN is Not-A-Number — the same as the value of
>   Number.NaN. In modern browsers, NaN is a non-configurable,
>   non-writable property. Even when this is not the case, avoid
>   overriding it.
>
> It is rather rare to use NaN in a program. It is the returned value
>   when Math functions fail (Math.sqrt(-1)) or when a function trying to
>   parse a number fails (parseInt("blabla")).

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)

Answer (score 0):

Would like to add some observations about **NaN** that intrigued me:

1. > `typeof(NaN)` returns `'number'`, but `isNaN(NaN)` returns `true`

Funny.

Also,

2. > `isNaN(10)` and `isNaN('10')` both return `false`
3. > `isNaN('')` returns `false`, but `isNaN('any alphabetical string')` returns `true`
4. > `isNaN(true)` and `isNaN(false)` return `false`. So boolean values are also considered as a number by `isNaN` function.