# is NaN a valid React child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when doing conditional rendering, if we do such thing:

```js
<p>{NaN && <div>Hello</div>}</p>
```

it will evaluate to `NaN` and will render it on screen. but in React document itself, `NaN` is not mentioned.

> A React node can be:
>
> - A React element created like `<div />` or `createElement('div')`
> - A portal created with `createPortal`
> - A string
> - A number
> - true, false, null, or undefined (which are not displayed)
> - An array of other React nodes

I confused about it.

https://react.dev/reference/react/isValidElement#isvalidelement

Comment: `NaN` is a number. And it says a number is a valid React node. Seems like it's explained.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10498549/17709311

Comment: @VLAZ thank you. may you give me a link about `NaN` to know more about it? I want to know why it is a Number.

Comment: See the linked duplicates. It's rather simple if you think about the problem of numbers. There are some things that just have to be numbers. If you do `3 * a` then the result *must* be a number as it's a numeric operation. However, if `a = "banana"` then there is no way to derive a sensible number from it. Yet it has to be a numeric value. Hence `NaN`. It is a value which is a marker for nonsensical numeric values. Anything that cannot usefully be converted to a number but does turns into `NaN`. Thus the domain of the result still remains just numbers without having to split it.

Comment: @VLAZ. wow. explained so well. I understood. thanks again 