# NaN javascript type

Tags: javascript

I have written below code in JS.

function foo() 
{

```
var s = "Jack";
s = parseInt(s);
console.log(s)
if (s!=NaN) {
    if (typeof (s) == "number")
        console.log("number");
    else if (typeof (s) == "string")
        console.log("string");
} else {
    console.log("Your entry is not a number");
}
```

}

As i am trying to parseInt a string, i got NaN as value.

We know that typeof(NaN) is  "number" and numbers can be compared directly like(1==1) in IF condition. But this didn't work.

I tried with isNaN(s) and it worked where as s!=NaN failed.

why ?

Comment: Probably better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/559792/218196 .

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The necessity of an isNaN function

> Unlike all other possible values in JavaScript, it is not possible to rely on the equality operators (`==` and `===`) to determine whether a value is `NaN` or not, because both `NaN == NaN` and `NaN === NaN` evaluate to false. Hence, the necessity of an `isNaN` function.[[*Ref*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description)]

**Conclusion:** `NaN`is never equals to anything including `NaN` itself hence rely on [**`Number.isNaN(value)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) method.

```js
console.log(NaN == NaN);
console.log(NaN === NaN);
console.log(NaN === undefined);
console.log(NaN === null);
console.log(NaN === 'TEST');
console.log(NaN === 0);
```

Comment: That's what the OP did. The question is not how to test for NaN by why the equality operator doesn't work:  *"I tried with isNaN(s) and it worked where as s!=NaN failed. Why?"*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values